# VBA: View code an Add-In that closes after opening

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Add-In that I created to update other Add-Ins as I release new versions. The AddIn runs when it opens (when Excel starts), it searches for new versions of other installed AddIns, and then the AddIn closes. If I try to open it from the code editor it just repeats this process. Any ideas on how I can access it?

Comment: You can't access the add-in's code? I'm not sure I'm following here.

Comment: No. The AddIn runs when it opens (when Excel starts), it searches for new versions of other installed AddIns, and then the AddIn closes. If I try to open it from the code editors it just repeats this process.

Comment: How are you trying to open the code such that the code runs?

Answer (score 2):

If you hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while an Excel file is opening, it will prevent any Automatic macros (e.g. the `Workbook_Open` event) from running.

Alternatively: Before you open the file, go to the Immediate Window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) in the VBA Editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) and run the following code

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

Then, when you are finished, run this to reset everything:

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

You *may* want to look into binding `GetKeyState`, so that your Macro can check for the Shift key before it does anything and `Stop` if it is held down

Comment: Although this often works for me, it doesn't when I've had to navigate through a file selection to open it.

Comment: @Mistella I have added an alternative, and a long-term solution

Comment: It also works when browsing to a file. Remember to press and hold shift when you click the "Open" button on the browse dialog.

Comment: `If I try to open [the add-in] from the code editor it just repeats this process` But they're saying their add-in runs when they open the code for it, not just the file into which it is loaded.